# How to get user input as string that has only zeros? in JAVA

Tags: java

In my application user can enter number between 0 to 999
However, whether he enter "0" or "00" or "000" should understood and treated differently.
All the functions that in know convert the input into single zero "0" before putting it into the variable.

```
private static void AddAmountChart1D (){
    String str_pana;
    int int_pana, Amount;
    Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the game pana : ");
    str_pana = UserInput.nextLine(); /* This line should treat "0", "00" & "000" as different types of strings.
    Presently it make all three as "0"
    System.out.print("Enter the Amount : ");
    Amount = UserInput.nextInt();
    int_pana = get_int_pana(str_pana);
    ChartAmount1D[int_pana] = ChartAmount1D[int_pana]+Amount;
}
```

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't. but if you parse it to an int, it will be turned into a single 0

Comment: read `String`, not `int`, then count zeroes and check whether it can be parsed into number. If you use `int`, only actual value is taken into account (which is `0`), not its textural representation (that could be `0`, `0x00`, `-0`, `00`, `000` etc)

Comment: Side note on code quality: read about the java coding style conventions. You are violating several of them: method names start with lowercase, you only use _ in CONSTANT_NAMES. Besides that, it seems that your code will be not doing what you expect. You turn str_pana into an int, to use it as index for an array; probably without checking it. Bad idea. And worse: 0, 00, 000 ... they are all 0. How do you think you can translate them to different, valid indices for your array access?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I am new to programming and trying to learn through free material available online. So I am not aware of standard styles & conventions used by professionals.
In method "get_int_pana", I am checking str_pana, if it is "00" then make index for array as 1001, if it is "000" then make it 1002, for all rest values between 0 to  999 leave it as it is.
The actual application is like this, consider numbers from 0 to 999, "00" and "000" these 1002 possibilities have an frequency associated with it.
Therefore I make an array of 1002 size and store frequency of each number in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your purpose is not that much clear to me.

But if you use

```
    UserInput.nextLine();
```

this will be treated as a String so it'll return the zeros like "0", "00" or "000".

Further if you want the value to be processed as a number simply use

```
    int number = Integer.parseInt(str_pana);
```

and use the number.

**Edit**

Please try this and check the results for "0", "00" or "000".

```
    if (str_pana.equals("0")) {
        System.out.println("Zero");
    }else if (str_pana.equals("00")) {
        System.out.println("Zero-Zero");
    }else if (str_pana.equals("000")) {
        System.out.println("Zero-Zero-Zero");
    }
```

Actually my point is to check the zeroes so that you can set the integer values in the if clause and convert them to respective integer values to be used later.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
In method "get_int_pana", I am checking str_pana, if it is "00" then make index for array as 1001, if it is "000" then make it 1002, for all rest values between 0 to  999 leave it as it is.
The actual application is like this, consider numbers from 0 to 999, "00" and "000" these 1002 possibilities have an frequency associated with it.
Therefore I make an array of 1002 size and store frequency of each number in it.
Even in my understanding "UserInput.nextLine()" should work as I want, but it is not happening. Am I missing some fine part that I should take care of?

Comment: @yatin-shah: Please check the edit section. It is really strange. What is the java version you're using by the way??

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as I wanted.
However, I find it strange that I was using 
If(str_pana == "0") 
This was not checking the string str_pana as required.
Your suggestion of using "str_pana.equals("0") works perfect.

Comment: @yatin-shah : In java equals() function checks the actual contents of the string but the == operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Read whole line. 
Use function

```
 public boolean startsWith("0")
```

From String class
If it doesn't return true - just parse.
Else count zeros

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I am new to JAVA. 
I could not understand your solution. Could you please elaborate?